# VueJS Send component props with space

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to send component props from my view but there is a space and it make vue return me `vendor.js:695 [Vue warn]: Error compiling template: - invalid expression: :user-name="Awesome Me"
- invalid expression: :user-name="Awesome Me"`

my view:

```
<ActionButton :id="1"
          :user-name="Awesome Me"
          :main="1" />
```

my components:

```
<script>
    export default{
        props: {
            id: {
                type: String
            },
            userName:{
                type: String
            },
            main: {
                type: Boolean
            }
        },
        methods: {
            setAsMain(id){
                // some stuff
            },

        },
        computed: {
            mainMessage(){
                return this.main == 1 ? 'Main character' : '';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I send the `user-name` value consist of space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem in not about space, You are using `v-bind` or `:` with props, while you are passing static data, so these are not needed, just do following:

```
<ActionButton id="1"
          user-name="Awesome Me"
          main="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I encontered the same issue and solved with:

```html
<ActionButton :user-name="'Awesome Me'" />
```

Notice that we must use another sigle quote,
I think vue would parse whatever in v-bind double quote as **code** rather that text.
For example, if I use:

```html
<ActionButton :buttonText="()=>'Awesome Me'" />
```

the text on button would be:

```
function() {return 'Awesome Me'}
```